# can't populate UITableView, source array valid

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch

I can't make my table view show my data, the array has valid data by the NSLog output. I put a breakpoint at the beginning of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and it never get there. Any ideas why?

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Ride.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableData *responseData;
@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize rideIds = _rideIds;
@synthesize rideNames = _rideNames;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"viewdidload");

    self.responseData = [NSMutableData data];


    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    // http://www.strava.com/api/v1/segments/229781/efforts?best=true

    // Efforts on segment by athlete limited by startDate and endDate
    //NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.strava.com/api/v1/segments/229781/efforts?athleteId=11673&startDate=2012-02-01&endDate=2012-02-28"]];

    //Leader Board on Segment all Athletes
    //NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.strava.com/api/v1/segments/229781/efforts?best=true"]];

    //Rides by Athlete
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.strava.com/api/v1/rides?athleteId=10273"]];


    //Twitter Example
    //NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1/trends"]];


    //Efforts by Ride
    //NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.strava.com/api/v1/rides/77563/efforts"]];

    //Effort Detail
    //NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.strava.com/api/v1/efforts/688432"]];


    //Google API Call
    //NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyAbgGH36jnyow0MbJNP4g6INkMXqgKFfHk"]];

/*    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ {
        NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    } ); */

        NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if(theConnection){
        self.rideIds = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        self.rideNames  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"No Connection");
        }





}


//Delegate methods for the NSURLConnection

//In order to download the contents of a URL, an application needs to provide a delegate object that, at a minimum, implements the following delegate methods: connection:didReceiveResponse:, connection:didReceiveData:, connection:didFailWithError: and connectionDidFinishLoading:.

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

    NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse");

    //This message can be sent due to server redirects, or in rare cases multi-part MIME documents.
    //Each time the delegate receives the connection:didReceiveResponse: message, it should reset any progress indication and discard all previously received data.

    [self.responseData setLength:0];
}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    [self.responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    NSLog(@"didFailWithError");
    NSString *errorDescription = [error description];
//    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connection failed: %@", errorDescription]);
    NSLog(@"Connection failed: %@", errorDescription);
}


- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading");
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[self.responseData length]);

    // convert to JSON
    NSError *myError = nil;
    //NSDictionary *jsonRes = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];

    NSDictionary *jsonResult = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];
    NSDictionary *jsonRides =[jsonResult objectForKey:@"rides"];


    // Show all values coming out of "rides" key
    // Store ride id's and names on arrays for later display on tableview
    for (NSDictionary *rides in jsonRides) {

        [self.rideIds addObject:[rides objectForKey:@"id"]];
        NSLog(@"id = %@", [rides objectForKey:@"id"]);
        //NSLog(@"%@",self.rideIds);

        [self.rideNames addObject:[rides objectForKey:@"name"]];
        NSLog(@"name = %@", [rides objectForKey:@"name"]);
        //NSLog(@"%@",self.rideNames);
    }
        NSLog(@"%@",self.rideIds);
        NSLog(@"%@",self.rideNames);

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    // Show all values coming out of NSKSONSerialization
    for(id key in jsonResult) {

        id value = [jsonResult objectForKey:key];

        NSString *keyAsString = (NSString *)key;
        NSString *valueAsString = (NSString *)value;

        NSLog(@"key: %@", keyAsString);
        NSLog(@"value: %@", valueAsString);
    }

    // extract specific value...
    // NSArray *results = [res objectForKey:@"results"];
    /*NSArray *results = [res objectForKey:@"rides"];
    for (NSDictionary *result in results) {
        NSData *athleteData = [result objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSLog(@"Ride name: %@", athleteData);
    }*/


/*    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ {
        [self.rideTableView reloadData];
    } ); */

    [self.rideTableView reloadData];


}



- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSLog(@"tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: ");

    //return self.rideIds.count;
    NSLog(@"%u",self.rideNames.count);
    return 3;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: ");


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if( nil == cell ) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text= [self.rideNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tv deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}



@end
```

NSLog content:

```
2012-08-18 18:47:29.497 WebServiceCall[10387:c07] viewdidload
2012-08-18 18:47:29.503 WebServiceCall[10387:c07] tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: 
2012-08-18 18:47:29.503 WebServiceCall[10387:c07] 0
2012-08-18 18:47:29.504 WebServiceCall[10387:c07] tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: 
2012-08-18 18:47:29.506 WebServiceCall[10387:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x14b6022 0xeb6cd6 0x14a2d88 0x395d 0xb3c54 0xb43ce 0x9fcbd 0xae6f1 0x57d42 0x14b7e42 0x1d87679 0x1d91579 0x1d164f7 0x1d183f6 0x1da5160 0x17e84 0x18767 0x27183 0x27c38 0x1b634 0x13a0ef5 0x148a195 0x13eeff2 0x13ed8da 0x13ecd84 0x13ecc9b 0x17c65 0x19626 0x22fd 0x2265 0x1)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

UPDATE: It seems that after passing through viewDidLoad it jumps right into `tableview:numberOfRowsInSection` method skipping all the 4 methods for handling `NSURLConnection` (where I updated my arrays).

My view controller is both delegate of my `NSURLConnection` AND my `tableView`. It seems that it's running first the tableView methods. Any suggestions as to how to make it run the `NSURLConnection` methods first ?

Comment: Perhaps you aren't its delegate or datasource.

Comment: Does it get to `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`?  If so, print the value you're returning.  In not, check the table's datasource connection.

Comment: delegate and datasource are connected and verified.

Comment: Very strange (your latest update with the NSLog).  If the numberOfRowsInSection is zero, it shouldn't be going into your cellForRowAtIndexPath method at all yet.  Two things to try:  implement `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and return 1 (this shouldn't matter, it should do this by default, but worth a try), and change your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` to return `self.rideNames.count` instead of rideIDs.count.

Comment: I don't know why but changing the return value from 3 to self.rideNames.count in tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: solved the problem. I think this was residual from previous tests but I thought it shouldn't be relevant... Anyway. I'm able to display my data right now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things you could try -- First, log self.rideIds.count in your numberOfRowsInSection method to make sure it's not returning 0. Second, at the end of your connectionDidFinishLoading method, put in a  [tableView reloadData] (or whatever the outlet to your table view is), that should take care of the problem of the table view methods being called before your connection is done.

After Edit: The error "-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array" is being caused by the "return 3" in your numberOfRowsInSection method. When the app starts up the table view will try to populate itself before your connection returns any results, so numberOfRowsInSection should return 0 not 3 the first time through, which it will do if you put back the return self.rideIds.count line.  If you do the reloadData at the end of the connection delegate methods, then the array will be populated and the table view should work properly.

Comment: it is returning 0 because the url connection methods are never being called, from viewdidload jumps straight to table methods. skipping all the json parsing and array feeding instructions. :(

Comment: That doesn't make sense -- those methods (at least the ones setting up the connection) have to be running if viewDidLoad is being called. Did you log connection to see if you got a valid connection object?  If not, then none of the delegate methods would be called.  But if that is valid, then you should at least get didFailWithError called if nothing else.

Comment: @marlex, have you set the controller that this code is in to be the delegate and data source for your table view?  I copied your code into a new app, and it worked fine for me (as far as I can tell -- the table view was populated).  One thing I changed, was to put back the commented out code in numberOfRowsInSection and comment out the "return 3"

Comment: @marlex, see my edited answer, the "return 3" was the cause of your error.

Comment: Yes I think that was the problem... the return value I set it to self.ridesNames.count ... it is working now after doing this small change.

Comment: @marlex, it may seem like a small change, but it's not good to mess with the number you return in that method.  If it returns 0, then the cellForRowAtIndexPath is never called and you get no error.  By returning 3 when there was really nothing in the array, you get the error when you try to call objectAtIndex on your array.

Answer (score 0):

Where is `tableView:numberOfSectionsInTableView:`? Perhaps that is returning **0** although the default is **1** if not set; You also need to set `delegate` and `dataSource` on your tableView.

Comment: delegate and datasource are connected and verified, i haven't implemented tableView:numberOfSectionsInTableView: is that necessary ? the problem seems to be that is running the tableview methods before the nsurlconnection ones, which are needed to populate my arrays of data used as datasource.

Comment: `tableView:numberOfSectionsInTableView:` is optional in your tableViewDataSource delegate.  If you don't implement this method it will always default to 1.

Comment: Just call `reloadData` on your tableView after your connection is done.

Comment: @WrightsCS I tried that but i don't understand why the nsurlconnection methods are not being called.